# Need help with NSXMLPaser tutorial

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, nsxmlparser

At the last part of the tutorial I am having an issue with the users variable, its saying users variable is undeclared.

It is being declared in my NSXMLPaser class that I created as a NSMutableArray and I am "#import"ing the header file of NSXMLPaser class...

Here is the link to the tutorial I am working through, any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

```
- (void) doParse:(NSData *)data {


    NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData * fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // create and init NSXMLParser object
    NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:fileData];

    // create and init our delegate
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    // set delegate
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    // parsing...
    BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

    // test the result
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"No errors - user count : %i", [parser [users count]]);  // users undeclared error here
        // get array of users here
        //  NSMutableArray *users = [parser users];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
    }

    [parser release];
    [nsXmlParser release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use "[parser.users count]" like Babji said or you could use the dot notation for everything, like "parser.users.count".

Also, you could use "[[parser users] count]". This means you first get the collection users of the parser ("[parser users]") and then you call count on that collection ("[[parser users] count]").

Answer (score 0):

use the users variable [parser.user count]